# Conditional expectation $ E(X^2|Y)$

Tags: probability

> Let $W=\{(x,y):(x^2)+(y^2)\leqslant 1\}$ with the sigma algebra of borel and with probability measure= Leb measure such that
> $$ P(A)= \frac{1}{\pi} \iint_{A} dx \; dy \qquad \forall  A \subset W  \ of\  borel $$
>
> Let $X(x,y)=x$ and $Y(x,y)=y$
>
> Calculate $$E(X^2|Y)$$

I tried with the definition of conditional expectation, that is, $$E (X^2*1_A)= E(E(X^2|Y)*1_A)) $$. Then I tried calculating $$ 1_A \iint_{W} X^2 dP $$, in order to be able to use $$ P(A)= \frac{1}{\pi} \iint_{A} dx \; dy $$ but I'm stuck here. I don't know exactly how to use $$ P(A) $$

Comment: So, what have you even tried?  You are expected to show you attempts so we may focus on where you are having difficulties.